# Laravel session doesn't work for other sub-domains

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, session, subdomain

I have a problem with the session in Laravel 5.3.

For our project, we have 2 sub-domain :

- 1 for developement's environment
- 1 for preproduction's environment

for the  first sub-domain no problem, it all works. But the second sub-domain nothing works. I concluded that the problem is the session, because on my second sub-domain, none cookies created.

I have look my session's file in my config and update any datas. This is my config session's file :

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 3600,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
| cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
| correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
|
*/

'store' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'name_cookie', // identique for all sub-domain but i have try to change the name for each domaine

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,
```

];

I don't found a solution despite much search,

Thanks

**I found the solution, my problem came from a bad configuration of the cloud front and not of laravel. Thanks at all for your help**

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ? `SESSION_DOMAIN=*.mydomain.com` so cookies produced in dev env would ba accessible for preprod env

EDIT : `SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.com` was the right answer, my bad

Comment: I come to try that, but none cookies saved for all my envs

Comment: yes with this config : SESSION_DOMAIN = api-dev.mydomain.com
For second domain : SESSION_DOMAIN = api-preprod.mydomain.com but not with *.mydomain.com

Comment: You can try the `null` value then, empty SESSION_DOMAIN or `.mydomain.com`the `*` should not be here

Comment: I found the solution, my problem came from a bad configuration of the cloud front and not of laravel. Thank you very much for your time and for your responses

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a wildcard domain for the SESSION_DOMAIN environnement variable

Edit: too late, stackexchange didnt show up the answers

Answer (score 0):

Test it out
`'domain' => '*.domain.com'`